# visual studio spring boot Non-resolvable parent POM behind company proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio, maven, visual-studio-code

I am new to visual studio trying to run spring boot demo application from visual studio tried this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot followed same step but getting this error in pom.xml
[image]

Added proxy entry also in maven setting.xml, since working behind organization proxy

```
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <host>companyproxy.apac.nsn-net.net</host>
  <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

when directly run DemoApplication.java getting main class not found error
[image]
and also CodeLens not showing for spring main class , where as if you have simple java application it shows run|debug

Comment: First using a repository manager would a better choice apart from that you should try to build your application from the plain command line via `mvn package -U` first....

Comment: It looks like a temporary network problem, the problem has been solved?

Comment: no problem still exist. did mvn package -U also which downloaded all the package but problem still exists

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem, could you upload your project here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this when I used the latest version of Springboot which is the **3.1.0-M2 version**. Maybe, because I am using the **Maven 3.9.1** and I think they have some compatibility issue with **Springboot 2 versions**.